# Genymotion emulator crashes on Windows 7 machine when running calabash-android tests

Tags: calabash

I am using Genymotion emulator to run my calabash android tests. I have around 7 feature files and after successfully running 3-4 features geny motion crashes with the following exception:

**"Player.exe has stopped working"**

**"Microsoft Visual c++ runtime Library

     The application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way"**

Unfortunately I am not able to post the images for this post.

Has anybody got a fix for this?

Thanks in advance!

-Nishi